# How to modify a text file so the last 4 signs of generated md5 digest match with md5 digest of the original file?

Tags: c++, hash, md5, collision

I need help with a problem, just an idea or algorithm is fine, I'm ok with coding.

I was asked to create a program counting the number of matching bits of md5 digests generated from a two slightly different text files. Then I had to make a digest from the file containing the code of that program (in C++) and modify my app to count the number of bits not matching in the previous files, then again generate a digest from the modified code.

That's as far as I got. The problem is that I have to modify the code that way, so the last 4 hex signs in generated digest (or 16 bits in general, or 2 bytes) must match the ones from the digest of unmodified program.

The overall idea was to make a program or algorithm generating the modified code on it's own by adding some commented lines at the end of the file, or maybe by using some kind of salting. I've read a lot about collisions, but I have no idea how to put that in use.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, be it anything, pseudocodes or tips. If it is required I can upload the programs I've made and generated hashes.

Comment: So basically produce md5 collisions on a smaller subset of the hash? Given that md5's designed to produce large changes in the entire hash if even a single bit of the input changes, you're going to have a very long search ahead of you.

Comment: That's a 112 bit match. While the chances of random strings having the same MD5 is even lower, getting a 112 bit match by chance is still utterly improbable. You will need a proper crypto approach, naive brute force will not suffice.